# How do you capture two leads

Tags: leads, design

I have a new job with a charity. We put in touch Volunteers and with schools, then I return school pay us a fee for the service.

My question is:

1. Volunteers are a lead ( when we recruit volunteers to help)
2. Schools are a lead ( this is when we get a school asking for a volunteers)

As you can see both Schools and Volunteers can be a lead, however they have different business process. How do you manage this process in Salesforce?

Comment: You can define Lead Process using different record types on Lead object. E.g. School and Volunteers would be two different record type on Lead Object.

Comment: +1 for Record type solution. You can still create custom objects to handle them.

Comment: @Devendra - that should be the answer

Answer (score 0):

Record types enable you to customize user's experiences, depending on their needs. You can use record types to offer different business processes, picklistvalues, and page layouts to different users based on their profiles.

Multiple business processes allow you to track separate sales, support, and lead lifecycles. A sales, support, lead, or solution process is assigned to a record type. The record type determines the user profiles that are associated with the business process.

You can go through below link where nice explanation given by Deepa Patel on Lead Process in Salesforce.

[Lead Process Example](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-define-lead-process-salesforce-deepa-patel)

You can able to find Lead Record types and Lead Process Under Setup Menu.

You can define Lead Process using different record types on Lead object. In your case, School and Volunteers would be two different record type on Lead Object.

[image]